# why flyway recognize dot as ©

Tags: flyway

I'm getting the following error when trying to do a Flyway migration

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.2.4.yqg:migrate (default-cli) on project yqg-flyway: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid version containing non-numeric characters. Only 0..9 and . are allowed. Invalid version: 111©1 -> [Help 1]

the filename is V111.1__add_table_corporate_account

the encoding setting in flyway is utf-8

Comment: Are you sure it is really a period (ASCII 46/0x2E)?

Comment: yes, i'm sure.[the screenshot of the file names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCT9k.png)